# Выделение определенного элемента (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

Почему при наведении только на первый элемент отображается иконка закрытия? В чем ошибка?

trooble.ru/test.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#msg').hover(function(e)
    {
        $('#msg a').show();
    }, function(e)
    {
        $('#msg a').hide();
    });
    $('#msg a').click(function(e)
    {
        $('#msg').detach();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @dmitriy kiryushin, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Спасибо, просто с сервисом еще не разобрался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя класс в качестве селектора, вы автоматически затрагиваете все элементы на странице. Исправьте скрипт на:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.msg').hover(function()
    {
        $('a',this).show();
    }, function()
    {
        $('a',this).hide();
    });
    $('.msg a').click(function()
    {
        $(this).closest('.msg').detach();
    });
});
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Answer (score 0):

используй класс вместо id, когда js ищет по id, он находит элемент и возвращает его прекращая дальнейшие поиски

Comment: С этим разобрался, теперь смотри trooble.ru/test.php при выделении одного элемента иконка отображается на всех элементах

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.msg').hover(function(e)
    {
        $('a',this).show();
    }, function(e)
    {
        $('a',this).hide();
});
```